Stuck on the last screen of installation and always Laggy
I have an HP laptop with i3 6006u and an AMD R5 M330 Gpu.
I always Use Safe Graphic Mode and tried the nomodeset thing but still laggy installation and stuck at last screen or crashed randomly.
I even tried Arch, Fedora, Mint...all have the same problem. Arch didn't even give me installation options.
Please help.
It was installed smoothly on an i3 1st Gen Hp laptop I still have.
